# Equivalent of ga:landingPagePath in GA4 Data API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

What would be the closest equivalent dimension of the API V3 "ga:landingPagePath" in GA4 Data API ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be this one for instance: To combine the dimension "landingPage", "sessionDefaultChannelGroup" with the metric "session".
There is a filter on Organic Search in this case to retrieve only the traffic related to SEO.

Example of API request:

```
{"dimensions":[{"name":"landingPage"},{"name":"sessionDefaultChannelGroup"}],"metrics":[{"name":"sessions"}],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2023-06-01","endDate":"yesterday"}],"dimensionFilter":{"filter":{"fieldName":"sessionDefaultChannelGroup","stringFilter":{"matchType":"EXACT","value":"Organic Search"}}}}
```